# Why can a `val` in a loop body take multiple values?

Tags: scala

I learned that

> 'val' are variables that are assigned once and never change, and only val's state change.

and as I know

> val could not be defined several times.

but when I execute following code (seems like socket consumer)

```
while (is.read(buf) > 0) {
  val input = new String(buf)
  println(input)
}
```

`println(input)` shows a different line each iteration. How could that happen?

It looks like `input` is constantly newly defined or `input` is not newly defined, and just modified several times.

Given that a `val` cannot change, how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object assigned to a `val` cannot be replaced.
`input` is defined only in the scope of the `while` loop, so it is destroyed and declared again in every iteration.

```
while (is.read(buf)>0)
{
    val input = new String(buf)   // declared afresh in every iteration
    println(input)
}                               // input is destroyed when you reach here
println(input)                 // input is not defined in this scope
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have initialized the val inside the loop. Each time the loop runs the older val is de-scoped and a new val is created with a new value.